# Destruição de uma instância

Tags: c#, .net, gerenciamento-de-memória

Como faço pra destruir uma instância?

Eu tenho um objeto cuja instância é referenciada em várias partes do meu código. Em dado momento eu preciso excluir esse objeto e pra isso estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
meuObjeto = null;
```

O problema é que esse código só está *setando* como `null` a variável `meuObjeto`. Nos demais pontos do sistema, o objeto ainda existe. Como faço para atualizar todas as referências em apenas um ponto do código?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se seria possível fazer algo assim. Enquanto alguma variável estiver apontando para o determinado objeto ele não será "limpo" pelo garbage collector, talvez se você fizesse ele implementar a  interface `IDisposable`, mas é difícil dizer se algo assim seria realmente correto para seu caso sem vem o código como um todo.

Comment: O que você precisa é `System.GC.SupressFinalize(Objeto)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# é uma linguagem com memória gerenciada, então você não destrói o objeto, ele será destruído quando não houver nenhuma referência para ele e a memória precisar do espaço dele. O *garbage collector* se encarregará disto.

É desnecessário colocar `null` no objeto, se ele não está sendo destruído é porque há referências para ele.

Então você só precisa deixar de usar o objeto. Provavelmente o código está segurando ele indevidamente. Teria que analisar o código para descobrir onde está o erro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.